# Windows 10 1607 keeps connecting to internet in the background

Tags: wsus, windows-update

I just installed windows 10 version 1607 and since yesterday i am seeing hidden connections to the internet.

I have wireshark installed and i see a constant connection to ips such as 23.14.84.171, 23.14.84.160, 216.58.192.110, 208.65.155.48, 13.107.4.50,
23.14.84.161,23.14.84.177, 23.14.84.168, 8.253.0.30, 8.253.0.62, 8.253.0.78.

Most of them identify as akamai technologies, but they also resolve to 
I am using a local WSUS server to deliver windows updates and i know it's working because i have deployed third party apps and i saw them being installed.

I uninstalled all metro apps through powershell, both provisioned apps and all apps from my user, including the windows store.

I disabled the windows store and metro app updates from gpedit. I also disabled some windows update scheduled taks. I have disabled windows 10's function of using peer to peer to download updates and even set the new working hours to avoid reboots. With all these the machine keeps downloading something.

I have uploaded a capture of sysinternal's tcpview to show all connections to akamai over at https://i.stack.imgur.com/msebH.jpg

The question is, is there a way for me to download whatever windows needs at wsus or am i stuck in waiting until it finishes? It has been 2 days downloading stuff (our internet speed is just 2MB and 200 users are behing the same connection)

Update: i got tired and created a firewall rule to block all those ips, but would like to know if there is a legit method to stop windows from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the delivery optimization feature introduced in Windows 10.  Here is a blog that explains further: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2016/08/16/windows-10-delivery-optimization-and-wsus-take-2/

You can disable this behavior in the UI here: https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-windows-update-delivery-optimization

Or via GPO here: support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3088114

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i stated that i already had disabled this "feature" (peer to peer download). I had to disable my firewall rule because windows update always stuck at 97%. In the end i had to leave whatever it was doing for days until it finished (it got quite a lot of interruptions)